# How to use @MailSessionDefinition in Wildfly

Tags: email, wildfly

I am trying to use the @MailSessionDefinition to configure a MailSender in Wildfly 8.2. Using just the annotation was not enough to setup, I had to use specific xml, present in Wildfly. Tips?

Here is my code:

```
@MailSessionDefinition(name = "java:jboss/mail/gmail",
host = "smtp.gmail.com",
user="user",
password="password",
transportProtocol = "smtps",
from="test@gmail.com",
properties = {
    "mail.debug=true",
    "mail.smtp.port=587",
    "mail.smtp.auth=true",
    "mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
})
public class MailConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: what exactly didn't work? and how did it present? Have any log deploying app that uses mail session definition?

Comment: I know this is moronic but -- I got my gmail mail session working after switching the smtp port from 587 to 465. Both are specified but they apparently worked differently.